# Unexpected looping in batch file rename

Tags: batch-file

I'm on XP Pro SP3, using a ".cmd" file to rename a group of files.

...Let's say I have the following files...
111.aaa
222.aaa
333.aaa
111.bbb
222.bbb
333.bbb
111.ccc
222.ccc
333.ccc
111.ddd
222.ddd
333.ddd
111.eee
222.eee
333.eee

...and I use the following code to rename the files...

```
for %%i in (*.ddd *.aaa) do ren "%%i" "---------- %%~i"  
for %%i in (*.aaa *.bbb *.ccc *.ddd *.eee) do ren "%%i" "xxxxx %%i"
```

...I end up with the following...
xxxxx ---------- 222.aaa
xxxxx ---------- 333.aaa
xxxxx xxxxx ---------- 111.aaa
xxxxx 222.bbb
xxxxx 333.bbb
xxxxx xxxxx 111.bbb
xxxxx 222.ccc
xxxxx 333.ccc
xxxxx xxxxx 111.ccc
xxxxx ---------- 222.ddd
xxxxx ---------- 333.ddd
xxxxx xxxxx ---------- 111.ddd
xxxxx 222.eee
xxxxx 333.eee
xxxxx xxxxx 111.eee

The first line of code finds the "aaa" and "ddd" files, and prefaces the filename with dashes.
The second line of code prefaces all filenames with Xs -- however, the first file in each group gets processed a second time, which is neither intended or desired!

While researching, I've seen references to ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, tokens, or delims -- but I can't find the examples I need to remedy my problem.

Any advice??

thanks...

PS:  It's been a real adventure formatting this post; it's not been Notepad copy&paste friendly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.ddd *.aaa') do ren "%%i" "---------- %%~i"
```

should cure your problem (modify your second line in like manner.)

What appears to be happening is that `for %%i...` processes the filenames as they are encountered but the second tranche resequences the names hence the new name may be encountered again.

The `dir` command builds a list of the filenames in memory, then processes the list so the changing directory sequence is bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I don't understand what exactly your problem is. This is your code:

```
for %%i in (*.ddd *.aaa) do ren "%%i" "---------- %%~i"  
for %%i in (*.aaa *.bbb *.ccc *.ddd *.eee) do ren "%%i" "xxxxx %%i"
```

And this is the description of your code/problem:

> The first line of code finds the "aaa" and "ddd" files, and prefaces
>   the filename with dashes.  The second line of code prefaces all
>   filenames with Xs -- however, the first file in each group gets
>   processed a second time, which is neither intended or desired!

If you want *not* to process the *.ddd nor *.aaa files in the second line, then use this in the second line:

```
for %%i in (*.bbb *.ccc *.eee) do ren "%%i" "xxxxx %%i"
```

Perhaps the description of your problem is not clear enough?

Comment: I appreciate your response; sorry for any ambiguity.  My desire was to prepend a subset of files and then prepend the superset of files...